# Commutativity of addition for class without friends

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there any easier way to realize commutativity of addition without using friend for class?
If I have a good understand, there is no possible to create two-arguments operator inside class.

```
class Myclass
{
private:
    int var;

public:
    Myclass() : var(0) {};
    void showVar() { cout << var << endl; }
    
    friend void operator+(Myclass&, int);
    friend void operator+(int, Myclass&);
};

void operator+(Myclass& obj, int x) { obj.var += x; }
void operator+(int x, Myclass& obj) { obj.var += x; }

void main()
{
    Myclass obj;

    obj + 5;
    obj.showVar();

    5 + obj;
    obj.showVar();
}
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The usual approach is to provide `operator+=` as a member function and then write `operator+` as a free function that uses `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Just define:

```
void operator+(int x, Myclass& obj) { obj + x; }
```

By the way, it is strange to use `operator+` this way. Normally, `i + 2` does not modify the value of `i`.

Comment: Yes I know It's against normal behaviour. I should create temporary object in operator, but why not? ;)

Comment: @VanQator at the very least it's unexpected (violated the principle of the least surprise). For modifying updates, there is `+=`.